# ORA-00933: SQL statement not ended

Tags: plsql

not seeing anything obvious

> ```
> Error at line 6
> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> ORA-06512: at line 16
> ```

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR PartTables IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS
    where TABLE_owner in ('FDW','FDWSTG','FDW3NF')
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_POSITION;

    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    r INTEGER;
    highValue VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
   FOR aTab IN PartTables LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT highValue;
      IF highValue NOT IN ('DEFAULT', 'MAXVALUE') THEN
         OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT ROWNUM FROM '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' PARTITION ('||aTab.PARTITION_NAME||') WHERE ROWNUM <= 1';
         FETCH cur INTO r;
         IF cur%NOTFOUND THEN
         
            dbms_output.put_line ('Partition dropped');
    --        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aTab.PARTITION_NAME||' UPDATE INDEXES';
         END IF;
         CLOSE cur;    
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to your database but I can make a guess at the problem.

I think your partition name `aTab.PARTITION_NAME` might not be a valid SQL identifier.  It might have symbols in it:

```
SQL> select rownum from some_table partition(some-part?name) where rownum <= 1;
select rownum from some_table partition(some-part?name) where rownum <= 1
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Or maybe it's just a number:

```
SQL> select rownum from some_table partition(0) where rownum <= 1;
select rownum from some_table partition(0) where rownum <= 1
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

This error can also be generated if the partition name is an SQL keyword such as `SELECT`, or if it is null.

If any case other than null, you will need to double-quote the partition name:

```sql
         --                                                                v------- add these -------v
         OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT ROWNUM FROM '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' PARTITION ("'||aTab.PARTITION_NAME||'") WHERE ROWNUM <= 1';
```